# Select a field from sql IF, otherwise select another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 fields in a table designated specifically to structure relations between ids. This means, for example, that one of those 3 fields is **first_id**, the other one is **second_id** and the third one is **the_third_one**. Each combination of **the_third_one** AND **first_id** AND **second_id** is ***"UNIQUE"***.

What I want to do is pick the first_id ***IF*** some **other_id** is equal to the second_id, or pick the second_id ***IF*** some **other_id** is equal to the first_id.

So basically, my table structure is like this

### `first_id   second_id   the_third_one`

`2323                 242            idrelatedstring`

`239                  231            anotherone`

And so on.

My **other_id** is *2323*. So what I want is to **retrieve** the **second_id AND the_third_one**.

My **other_id** is *231*. So what I want is to **retrieve** the **first_id AND the_third_one**.

How should I proceed to query the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `case when then`

**Example**:

```
select
  third_id,
  case when other_id = second_id then first_id 
       when other_id = first_id  then second_id
  end as id
from my_table
where ....
```

Comment: I had to chose this one for the `end as id` part, just what I needed!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
select '2nd, 3rd' as which, second_id as val1, the_third_one as val2
  from tbl
 where first_id = '2323'
union all
select '1st, 3rd' as which, first_id, the_third_one
  from tbl
 where second_id = '2323'
```

Replace the literal (2323) with a prompt if that is your intention.